# Sourcesafe searching

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I need to do a significant search through my SourceSafe 8 database to support a refactoring exercise.

I have a list of about 250 differant stored procedures that are called and need to work out where in the application. Are there any tools that improve on the standard search so that I can search for any instance of any of these procs or is pulling the code into another database my best bet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't laugh but I still use SourceSafe 6... but there is a Find in Files option from the tools menu that will do a search within files for a specific string... do you have that available in version 8?

Comment: I'm not laughing because you use SourceSafe 6, but the fact that you use SourceSafe at all...(not trying to be a jerk, but SourceSafe burned me one time and it is the only piece of software I can say that I absolutely despise).

Comment: Yeah that's what we have at work... at home I'm using SVN now and like it much better.

Comment: I can use find in files; but its 1 search string at a time; and the results output is terrible.

Comment: You may be best off writing a quick little app to do this for you.  The SourceSafe objects work really nicely in visual studio. Seems a lot quicker too.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [vssfind](http://www.urbanresearch.com/software/utils/vssfind/) utility, a freeware, and see if helps.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft Visual SourceSafe Explorer Version 8, the **View/Search** menu provides access to the following search capabilities:

- **Wildcard Search** *(On the file name. Use a question mark to match a single character in the file name, and an asterisk to match zero or more characters.)*

  - Search Area

    - Search in current project only
    - Search in current project and all subprojects
    - Search in all projects
- **Status Search**

  - Display all checked out files
  - Display files checked out to: [user name]
  - Search Area

    - Search in current project only
    - Search in current project and all subprojects
    - Search in all projects

For the first two Search Area options, the search settings will be applied as you click from project to project. Remember to go back and clear your search settings after you've found your files of interest.